# What text editor (for windows or linux) can display the byte order mark in text files?

Tags: unix

What text editor (for windows or linux) can display the byte order mark in text files?

Comment: I believe this belongs to superuser.

Comment: Why do you want to know, and why do you want to use a text editor?  This might be a place where a hex-editor might be more appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

[VIM](http://www.vim.org) allows you to verify the presence and change the BOM in a file, but the BOM is not "displayed", since it is not part of the intended text contents of the file. Check the options 'bomb' and 'fileencoding'.

```
:help 'bomb'
:help 'fileencoding'
```